# Why is the same object returned?

Tags: android, function

Here is the code:

```
 sealed class UseCaseException(override val cause: Throwable?) :Throwable(cause) {

    class LocationException(cause: Throwable) :
    UseCaseException(cause)
    class UnknownException(cause: Throwable) :
    UseCaseException(cause)

    companion object {
    fun extractException(throwable: Throwable):UseCaseException {
    return if (throwable is UseCaseException)
              throwable 
              else 
                UnknownException(throwable)
           }
    }
  }
```

What is the reason for returning `UnknownException` when it is also a `throwable`. I mean when `if` checks `throwable` and finds that it is an `UnknownException`, it returns it, so the `else` branch is never reached. Why is it there?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Why not just do this: return `throwable as UseCaseException`?